# ctags cannot open option file ".ctags"

Tags: ctags

ctags is not seeing my `~/.ctags` file, so I've tried specifying it using the `--options` option but it always says it cannot find the file, no matter where I put it:

```
$ touch .ctags && ctags --options=.ctags
ctags: cannot open option file ".ctags" : No such file or directory
```

I'm using the latest homebrew version (5.8) and I've tried using HEAD as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The fix for me was to change `.ctags` to `.ctags.cnf`. I have no explanation why this worked. But it seems that Exuberant Ctags requires an extension, I changed it to `.ctags.bak` it it works as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the full path to the ctags options: `/Users/your_username/.ctags` instead of `~/.ctags`

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly off-topic but I've had the same problem on Windows.
I had a batch file called `ctags.bat` which contained the following line:

```
"C:\SOME_DIRECTORY\Vim Tools\ctags.exe" --options="%CD%\ctags.cnf"
```

This line was expanded into:

```
"C:\SOME_DIRECTORY\Vim Tools\ctags.exe" --options="MY_CURRENT_DIRECTORY\ctags.cnf"
```

Ctags was giving me the same error:

```
ctags.exe: cannot open option file "MY_CURRENT_DIRECTORY\ctags.cnf" : No such file or directory
```

Escaping the last `\` made it work, i.e. I changed the line to:

```
"C:\SOME_DIRECTORY\Vim Tools\ctags.exe" --options="%CD%\\ctags.cnf"
```

Note the `\\` before  `ctags.cnf`

Regarding your problem on linux: try to add quotes around '.ctags':

```
ctags --options='./.ctags'
```